# How do I conditionally format all cells that begin with an equals sign?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use conditional formatting in Google Sheets to only format cells that are formulas (i.e. begin with an = sign)? For example, I would like a cell containing `=F2*30` to be highlighted while a cell containing `150` would not be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A1:Z`:

```
=isformula(A1)
```